# Reading XML from PowerShell command

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a XML file generated from one operation. I need to extract few values via PowerShell for the below XML file.

```xml
<TABLE BORDER=0><TR><TD><img src="/_file.gif"<A HREF="/TestSandbox-Build-Artifacts/TB-Alpha-App_Installer.apk">Bubbles_Install_13</a>&nbsp;</TD><TD ALIGN=right>2459427535 bytes&nbsp;</TD><TD>Jul 1, 2019 12:35:52 AM</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><img src="/_file.gif alt="(file)">&nbsp;<A HREF="/Test/sharTestSandbox-Build-Artifacts/UnitTests.zip">UnitTests.zip</a>&nbsp;</TD><TD ALIGN=right>435316365 bytes&nbsp;</TD><TD>Jul 1, 2019 12:36:10 AM</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><A HREF="/Test/shared/build-latest/TestSandbox-Build-Artifacts/buildInfo.json">buildInfo.json</a>&nbsp;</TD><TD ALIGN=right>220 bytes&nbsp;</TD><TD>Jul 1, 2019 12:36:10 P<M</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
```

I have tried couple of commands in PowerShell but both of them give same error.

```bsh
$file = "C:\Users\amit\Desktop\Builds\Output.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)
```

```bsh
$file = "C:\Users\amit\Desktop\Builds\Output.xml"
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load($file)
```

For the 1st command I get the following error.

```
Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument".
Error: "'0' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''.
Line 2, position 48."
At line:4 char:1
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument
```

For the 2nd command

```
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "'0' is an unexpected token.
The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 2, position 48."
At line:6 char:1
$xml.Load($file)
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I am unable to get if its a issue with the output file generated or is there issue with my syntax.

Comment: The instruction `$xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)` works with my XML file. Probably you have an invalid content in your XML file?

Comment: Your input data isn't XML, but an incomplete and broken HTML fragment. XML parsers expect well-formed input.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thank you for reply. Is there any other way to read this HTML fragment using powershell??? I want to avoid using any other scripting language like python and ruby because i would want to use this solution across multiple systems and want to avoid install setups required for other languages

Comment: Since the fragment is broken the usual parsers won't help, so you're probably stuck with extracting the desired values via regular expression matches.